# Как отсортировать структуру по выбранному полю

Tags: c, структуры

"Имеется структура состоящая из различных полей. Также имеется массив этих структур. Цель: написать универсальную функцию, которая сортировала бы массив по выбранному пользователем полю."
Вопрос: возможно ли это вообще сделать на С без использования кучи `if` конструкций? Если да, то как можно динамически обращаться к нужному полю структуры? Думал как то плясать от указателя на базовый адрес структуры в памяти, но это работало бы если бы все поля занимали равное количество байт.

Answer (score 1):

Конечно, можно сделать без множества if'ов. Вам следует написать или найти на Си какой-нибудь из стандартных алгоритмов сортировки ([вставками](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8), [пирамидальная](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0), [слиянием](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC), [быстрая](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D1%8B%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0)) и добавить обращения к полям Ваших структур. То есть, там, где в обычной сортировке чисел обращение идёт напрямую к элементу массива, Вам нужно обращаться к полю элемента массива.

В стандартной библиотеке C++ есть готовые алгоритмы сортировки, туда только итераторы массива и функцию сравнения отправить надо. Не исключено, что на просторах интернета найдётся нечто подобное готовое для Си.

И лучше бы хранить не массив структур, а массив *указателей* на структуры, чтобы не тратить время на копирование значений структур при их смене местами. Вообще, это одна из причин существования указателей.